# adding favourite button to html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

ISSUE: I got a small issue with this.Issue Happened when I created 2 html files (Like for different category of Books) with same code only difference in the name of books.Say the Html 1 has data-id's [Book A],[Book B ],**[Book C]**. and html 2 has **[Book C]**,[BookD],[BookE],[BookF] etc. When I opened Html 1 & added [BookA],[BookB] to localstorage & closed the file and opened html 2 and added [BookC] to localstorage. when I opened html 1 again [BookA],[BookB] got cleared & now both files has only [BookC],

The Problem is when I opened html 2  and  it has no [BookA],[BookB] & I selected [BookC] then localstorage reset and saves only [BookC] .
Can you help me  to fix  this . Thanks in advance

I donot Know How many updates are allowed to single question.If This is wrong Moderators please forgive

EDIT (Old) :Can  please tell me what changes to jquery for getting   code work in below Case . becauses code doesn't work when  adding multiple 'td's under same tr
also doesnot work when i have anything on unicode characters.
i want only serial code saved to localstorage and retreive by identifying it

How can I make this happen:

> when user select add to the favourite image or something like a button, it becomes yellow-colored (added to favorites). And the favoured item should be placed above the unfavoured item. the table is saved to localStorage.

can this be achieved by using localStorage script or jquery?

```
    <table><tr>
    <td >ല്ലെങ്കിൽ (Eg For Book name in another lang )</td>
    <td  style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-dais</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="../files/images/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="../files/images/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td >The chair by Jhon</td>

    <td  style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-jhon</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="../files/images/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="../files/images/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
          <td>The Lady by Maria</td>

    <td  style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-lady</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="../files/images/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="../files/images/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE. I made you a snippet. Please add your coding efforts to the JavaScript pane and perhaps add some images from placeholder.com and some CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistakes in asking question.

Comment: Can you please update the question with your efforts?

Comment: @mplungjan Sir I Updated Question , Please Refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to move and save

The HTML has to be valid (I had to fix your `</table>`)

***UPDATE*** To have different localStorage entries per table, you can for example give the table a class and an ID and do

```
localStorage.setItem(
  document.querySelector("table.bookTable").id+"favs",
  JSON.stringify(favs)
);
```

[Full example](https://plungjan.name/SO/bookrating/allbooks.html)

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
    $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
    const $favs = $("tr").has('img.yellow-star:visible');
    $("table").prepend($favs)
    const favs = $favs.find("td").text().trim().split(/\s+/)
    //localStorage.setItem("favs",JSON.stringify(favs)); // uncomment this on server
  })
  let favs // = localStorage.getItem("favs"); // uncomment when on your server
  // favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : []; // uncomment when on your server
  favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : ["cat", "foo"]; // remove this after testing
  $.each(favs, function(i,fav) {
    $("table tr td:contains(" + fav + ")").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().trigger("click")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  height: 25px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>duck</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goose</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With your new HTML

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
    $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
    const $favs = $("tr").has('img.yellow-star:visible');
    $("table").prepend($favs)
    const favs = $favs.find("td:first").map((i,fav) => $(fav).data("id")).get();
    //localStorage.setItem("favs",JSON.stringify(favs)); // uncomment this on server
  })
  let favs // = localStorage.getItem("favs"); // uncomment when on your server
  // favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : []; // uncomment when on your server
  favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : ["Book A","Book C"]; // remove this after testing
  $.each(favs, function(i, fav) {
    $("table tr td[data-id='"+fav+"']").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().trigger("click")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  height: 25px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book A">ല്ലെങ്കിൽ (Eg For Book name in another lang )</td>
    <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-dais</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book B">The chair by Jhon</td>
    <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-jhon</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> ലോഡ് </td>
    <td data-id="Book C" style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-lady</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Separate ratings for tables - not I added a class and an ID to the table

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function(e) {
    const $parentTable = $(this).closest("table"); 
    $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
    $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
    const $favs = $("tr").has('img.yellow-star:visible');
    $parentTable.prepend($favs)
    const favs = $favs.find("td:first").map((i,fav) => $(fav).data("id")).get();
    //localStorage.setItem($parentTable.attr("id")+"favs",JSON.stringify(favs)); // uncomment this on server
  })
  let favs // = localStorage.getItem($(".ratingTable").attr("id")+"favs"); // uncomment when on your server
  // favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : []; // uncomment when on your server
  favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : ["Book A","Book C"]; // remove this after testing
  $.each(favs, function(i, fav) {
    $("table tr td[data-id='"+fav+"']").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().trigger("click")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  height: 25px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="ratingTable" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book A">ല്ലെങ്കിൽ (Eg For Book name in another lang )</td>
    <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-dais</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book B">The chair by Jhon</td>
    <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-jhon</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> ലോഡ് </td>
    <td data-id="Book C" style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-lady</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210886/discussion-on-answer-by-mplungjan-adding-favourite-button-to-html-table).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        $(".fav").click(function()
        {
            if($(this).children("img").prop("src")=="unfav.png")
            {
                $(this).children("img").prop("src", "fav.png");
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).children("img").prop("src", "unfav.png");
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

> Remove any one image in .fav < div >

Answer (score 0):

Is this the effect you are after? Then you need to `toggle()` the stars on `click`.
I used jQuery for the ease of demonstration. It can easily be translated into vanilla JS.

```js
var myVars = {
  'cat': false,
  'duck': false,
  'goose': false,
  'foo': false,
  'bar': false
};
localStorage.setItem('myVars', JSON.stringify(myVars));
$('tr').click(function(e) {
 $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
 $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
  var name = $(this).attr('id');
  var status = $(this).find('img.yellow-star').is(':visible');
  changeMyVar(name, status);
  moveToTop(name);
});

function changeMyVar(name, status) {
  var tempMyVars = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myVars'));
  tempMyVars[name] = status;
  localStorage.setItem('myVars', JSON.stringify(tempMyVars));
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('myVars'));
}

function moveToTop(name) {
  var thisTr = $('#vars_table').find('tr#'+name);
  $('#vars_table').find('tr#'+name).remove();
  $('#vars_table').prepend(thisTr);
}
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
img {
  height: 25px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="vars_table">
  <tr>
    <td>cat</td>
    <td> 
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>duck</td>
    <td> 
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>goose</td>
    <td> 
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td> 
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td> 
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/9bfb21466fc07c2f2795fce51bb5ee4f_28-collection-of-star-clipart-transparent-background-high-_299-270.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://cdn.clipart.email/d09d2061abdc8c1316827ecafedacf01_stars-clipart-on-transparent-background-clipartxtras_7628-7405.png" />
      </div></td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: but how can the favoured item shows on top and modified table save into localStorage ?

Comment: @DavidBeckam Keep an object in the localStorage to store your stati, and update them onClick. I updated my above snippet, but it won't run in JS Fiddle due to security restrictions. But the code works.

Comment: @DavidBeckam Awesome, then you can accept the answer for future reference.