# Favorite button/image on HTML table activating when clicking anywhere in the row

Tags: html, jquery

I was able to copy Jquery code from this previous question ([adding favourite button to html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812468/adding-favourite-button-to-html-table)) to create a favorites functionality in my html table.

Unfortunately the script activates the favorite/unfavorite script whenever the row is clicked on rather than **just** when the star image is clicked. It is simple enough to trigger the 'click' function just for the button by pointing to the 'div' rather than 'tr' but when i do so the script breaks in some way as refreshing the page doesn't store the favorite/unfavorite image elements.

HTML code can be found in the above linked question.

The original question/reply has the working code sample here: https://plungjan.name/SO/bookrating/allbooks.html . Note that if you click anywhere in the row it will activate code rather than just the star.

TLDR: how do i change above Jquery script to work when i only want to click on the star rather than the whole row?

Relevant code below:

```
const showFavs = function(key, favs) {
  if (!favs) return;
  key = key.replace("favs", ""); // this could be cleaner
  favs = JSON.parse(favs);
  $.each(favs, function(i, fav) {
    const selector = "#" + key + " tr td[data-id='" + fav + "']";
        $(selector).closest("tr").trigger("click"); // click the TR
  });
};

$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function(e) {
    const $parentTable = $(this).closest("tbody");
    $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
    $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
    const $favs = $("tr", $parentTable).has('img.yellow-star:visible');
    const favs = $favs.find("td:first").map((i, fav) => $(fav).data("id")).get();
    localStorage.setItem($parentTable.attr("id") + "favs", JSON.stringify(favs));
  })
  // read all favs and trigger them
  Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
    if (key.endsWith("favs")) showFavs(key, localStorage.getItem(key));
  });

  const $onlyRated = $("#onlyrated");
  if ($onlyRated.length>0) {
    $onlyRated.on("click",function() {  
      if (this.checked) {
        $("tr").find('img.white-star:visible').each(function() {
          $(this).closest("tr").hide();
        });
      }    
      else {
        $("tr").find('img.white-star').each(function() {
          $(this).closest("tr").show();
        });
      }    
    });  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `tr` is clicked, you can check if the actual element that was clicked is a *"star"*. If it is, then you run the code, otherwise ignore it. Try this

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr').click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('.fav img')) {
      $(this).find('img.white-star').toggle();
      $(this).find('img.yellow-star').toggle();
      const $favs = $("tr").has('img.yellow-star:visible');
      $("table").prepend($favs)
      const favs = $favs.find("td:first").map((i, fav) => $(fav).data("id")).get();
      localStorage.setItem("favs", JSON.stringify(favs));
    }
  });

  let favs = localStorage.getItem("favs");
  favs = favs ? JSON.parse(favs) : [];
  $.each(favs, function(i, fav) {
    $("table tr td[data-id='" + fav + "']").each(function() {
      $(this).parent().find('.white-star').trigger('click')
    });
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book A">ല്ലെങ്കിൽ (Eg For Book name in another lang )</td>
    <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-dais</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book B">The chair by Jhon</td>
    <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-jhon</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-id="Book C"> ലോഡ് </td>
    <td style="display:none" class="serial-code">book-lady</td>
    <td>
      <div class="fav">
        <img class="white-star" src="https://i.postimg.cc/g0b9JG0w/unfav.png" />
        <img class="yellow-star hide" src="https://i.postimg.cc/QN1T9bSH/fav.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Credit**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59828700/6214210
**Note**: `localStorage` does not work in the snippet so you have to test it locally.

Comment: @ruleboy21 i tried and still no dice. Within a browser session it seems to work great but on refresh all the images are white stars even if they were favorited previously. I inspected the page while running and can see the key/value pairs are being completely overwritten on refresh. Added all jquery that i'm using in the original question. Thanks!

Comment: @MathiasWainer it is working like I said. Check out a working demo here https://achlamydeous-adapti.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: @ruleboy21 you are right! got it to work. I was using a different method of getting the favorites from local-storage so it was not working with the IF wrapper. Thank you very much! will mark your answer as correct